# Issue with members adding in telegram group through python

Tags: python, telegram, python-cmd

I am trying to add members to a telegram group using python-cmd through GitHub (Telegram adder & scrapper script). I am done with all processes correctly, at last members were not added to the group.

Can someone guide me through this process...
Please refer below screenshot for more details.

Comment: Dear, firstly there are no ss visible below. And also wouldn't that be lovely if you have elaborated your question by supplying us with console outputs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.